# ReactNative: navigationOptions not working

Tags: header, react-native, react-navigation

Not able to change the headertitle or headerstyle using the navigationOptions function. Also used defaultNavigationOptions instead but still not working.

```
    const CategoriesScreen = props => {
  const renderGridItem = itemData => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.gridItem}
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'CategoryMeals' });
        }}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>{itemData.item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      data={CATEGORIES}
      renderItem={renderGridItem}
      numColumns={2}
    />
  );
};

CategoriesScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: 'Meal Categories',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : ''
  },
  headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide full code with your navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong as you should use the title instead of headerTitle like

```
  title: 'Meal Categories',
```

instead of

```
  headerTitle: 'Meal Categories',
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced The same Problem. In my case, I just had to reload my app